# ASP.NET Identity 2.x with external REST web service as user/role store

Tags: asp.net-mvc, web-services, asp.net-identity-2

I'd like to use ASP.NET Identity 2.x (.NET 4.6.1 / MVC5), without talking to a database directly through Entity Framework, but instead using an external (REST) web service as the source of users and roles.  I've read up a little bit on this already, but I was just curious if anyone knows what would be the minimum interfaces to implement.  I would assume IUserStore and IRoleStore would be absolute minimum, correct?

I'm aware of these resources:

- [Simple Asp.net Identity Core Without Entity Framework](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Simple-Aspnet-Identiy-Core-7475a961)
- [Exorcising Entity Framework from ASP.NET Identity](http://blog.markjohnson.io/exorcising-entity-framework-from-asp-net-identity/)
- [ASP.NET Identity w/o Entity Framework](http://methoddev.com/blg/let-s-talk-software/336/asp-net-identity-w-o-entity-framework)

...but nobody particularly talked about using a web service, and they're mainly focusing on just not using EF, but are still using a DB of some kind directly.  I am curious if anyone has tried this with a web service and has come across any pitfalls?

Comment: a web service still needs to store its information ***somewhere***, that place is usually a db.

Comment: Yes, but that's fundamentally different from talking to a DB directly, from the perspective of the ASP.NET Identity.  It would only be making calls to an external web service to interact with user data, so there would be no Entity Framework or any other DB-related code in the MVC web application using Identity.

Comment: @Jiveman Did you end up implementing this? I am looking for somehting similar, with Idenitity 3 (ASP.NET Core Identity) now...

Comment: Sort of. It's still a work-in-progress, but I've decided to not worry about ASP.NET Identity for now, so I'm basically doing Claims Authentication with Owin, but without any ASP.NET Identity. Basically, I don't even have a reference for Asp.Net.Identity in my project.